# How would I make a plane with a hollow cylinder and a flat bottom, like a skateboard half pipe?

Tags: objects

How would I make a plane with a hollow cylinder and a flat bottom, like a skateboard half pipe?

I am just thinking about making a primitive shape. No details are other than a shape. A side view would be akin to this " --U--" but flush with the top and a bit of flat bottom.

This is my first blender project, so I hope this question is appropriate.

Comment: Hello, could you please a photo of the shape?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add a mesh circle, select the upper part and delete it

[image]

now select the right part

[image]

and move it to the right

[image]

now select these two vertices

[image]

and subdivide

[image]

select the vertex in the middle and use snap -> vertex

now press G Y and move the cursor on this vertex so that the selected vertex has the same height

[image]

then move that vertex to the right like this:

[image]

now select these two vertices

[image]

and press E S X and move your mouse so you got this:

[image]

now press A E Z and move your mouse you will get:

[image]

now TAB and right click -> autosmooth

[image]